# How to debug "Installation Check failure" error in Mac App Pkg installers?

Tags: macos, installation, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I am testing an application I created in Xcode. I archived it then clicked 'Shared' on the Organizer. From there I chose "Mac OSX App Store Package".

When launch the created pkg file then it immediately quits with 'MyApp can’t be installed on this computer' message. The system log has only the following log.

```
07/02/12 10:56:01.793 AM Installer: Installation check failure.  . MyApp can’t be installed on this computer..
```

How do I debug and find the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem now. Do you ever find the solution?

Comment: @Suresh Nopes. I did not.

Comment: Then what did you do?. Now I am using IceBerg to create the pkg file.

Comment: I simply moved on to using MacStore.

Answer (score 19):

You can check the Install log file for issues related to installers. File Path: /var/log/install.log.

Comment: Make sure you scroll all the way to the bottom (`SHIFT+G` in vim)

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing from a command line, you can also redirect the logs to a specific file (using dumplog)

```
sudo installer yourpackage.pkg -target \ -dumplog yourLogFile.log
```

See also: [installer help](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/installer.8.html)

Comment: `-dumplog` is a option and has no arguments. You can use `.. -dumplog > yourLogFile.log`